# Printing or Exporting Table on ArcGIS Online?

Tags: export, printing, arcgis-online

I have a table that is filtered on my ArcGIS Online map. The data for this map is from a feature layer that I created using ArcGIS Online by importing the features from a shapefile or .csv.

How would I print or export that filtered table?

I thought it would be a simple task, but I cannot locate any information on the subject.

Comment: Do you mean printing tables from layout using "Add table to Layout" or thru python script ?

Comment: I have not actually heard of "Add Table to Layout" but it sounds useful.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to clarify whether your ArcGIS for Server is providing a map, feature or geoprocessing service that you are trying to consume in ArcGIS Online, please?

Comment: When I created this question we were using ArcGIS for Server. Now we are strictly using ArcGIS Online for cost and functionality reasons. I updated the question.